# What new in the F# Runtime SP1?

Tags: f#

What the difference between F# 2.0 Runtime and F# 2.0 Runtime SP1?

F# Runtime 2.0:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13450

F# Runtime 2.0 SP1:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15834

They seem identical to me.

Comment: Probably bug fixes if nothing else.

Comment: I found some documentation on whats new here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service pack was just bug fixes; there are no new features.

Comment: _Important_ bug fixes, however, such as fixing `DllImportAttribute` and `CallingConvention`.